# Dynamic products price according to ordered amounts

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I want to the price of my products to change according to the ordered quantity.

Ideally, i would like to see the price of the product dynamically change on the product page, according to the selected quantity.

Is there any module doing it in Ubercart ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with custom price: http://drupal.org/project/uc_custom_price